# How to open a external link on IE browser instead of Metro IE with WinJS

Tags: internet-explorer, winjs

I am developing a metro app in WinJS which opens on a external browser (MetroIE) a link like this:

```
  var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri("http://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX:XXXX/test/AU/jsp/AU000007.jsp?data=" + jcrypto(message));

    //opens the url on external browser
    Windows.System.Launcher.launchUriAsync(uri).done(
        function (success) {
            if (success) { console.log("page opened correctly"); }
            else { console.log("an error has occured"); }
            });
```

but I want the link on normal IE11 browser, how do I do that???

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to open a url with parameters in external browser with WinJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20707937/how-to-open-a-url-with-parameters-in-external-browser-with-winjs)

Comment: nope, I did that question, first I wanted to know how to open it on a external browser, now I want it to be IE instead of MetroIE app

Comment: Your other question says: "but it just opens the link on my metro app, how to fix that???" I don't see how is this different?

Comment: And just to answer this anyway... [`launchUriAsync`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh701476) is the way to open URLs in an external application, which is why @WiredPrairie posted it. If it's not working, I would update that other question since it contains more information.

Comment: yup it opens on external app, IE Metro is an external app I did say my metro app (developed by me) which is different of IE Metro, now I want that link to be oppened on normal IE, the reason is because of WeppApps interaction, If I have a session on a Specific WebBrowser (Ex Normal IE11) and I want to send some parameters back, but if this stills open my links on IE Metro browser my other session is not beign used anymore

Comment: I see what you're saying. Unfortunately, I don't think you will be given the option to do so. You cannot launch a specific application from within your Metro app. To launch a URL it launches whatever the default application for that content type is (`http`). In my case it would start Firefox. The user can select the non-metro IE11 if they want, but you can't decide what application to open that URL in.